# Complimentary N - P mosfet circuit does not fully turn off

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

The following circuit does not operate as I hoped. There is between 1.5-1.6V on the output when the input is low. The circuit switches high correctly (Vout = 24V) and there doesn't appear to be any overcurrent as it does so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDLUpq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have tried disconnecting the NPN driver circuit and directly connecting the gates to ground. This has negligible effect. This leads to me to believe the top N-Channel mosfet has been damaged, although I'd also expect the P-Channel to conduct and I would see a large current draw. This doesn't appear to be happening.

I cannot discount damage to the mosfets as these have come from a donor board.

If there anything glaringly obvious that I have missed please say so.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what? Why are you using a P Fet on the low side and N-Fet on the high side? N Fets make great low side switches and P-Fets make great high side switches. (Also, what is their maximum Vgs rating?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like what I would expect from that circuit.

If you ground the gates, then M2 will pull down until the output is equal to the threshold voltage, which appears to be 1.5-1.6 V.

If you want 0 V on the output when the input is low, then you have to either pull the gates a couple of volts further down (according to the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/115/DMG4407SSS-219240.pdf), you have 1 V left before the absolute maximum). Or place the N-MOS at the bottom and P-MOS at the top, which is how complementary half-bridges are usually made.

If you are going to make a typical half-bridge, then you should take some precautions. [Here's](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+5e-10+16.817414165184545+60+5+50%0Af+688+144+752+144+1+1.5+0.2%0Ad+640+144+688+144+1+0.805904783%0Ar+576+144+640+144+0+10%0Ar+576+176+688+176+0+470%0Ac+688+176+688+208+0+1e-9+23.972829311824192%0Aw+688+144+688+176+0%0Aw+576+144+576+176+0%0AR+752+128+752+80+0+0+40+24+0+0+0.5%0Af+688+288+752+288+0+1.5+0.2%0Aw+752+160+752+272+0%0Aw+752+160+832+160+2%0Ar+832+160+896+160+0+1000%0Aw+896+160+944+160+2%0Ag+688+208+688+224+0%0Ag+688+352+688+368+0%0Aw+576+288+576+320+0%0Aw+688+288+688+320+0%0Ac+688+320+688+352+0+1e-9+22.70262934817045%0Ar+576+320+688+320+0+470%0Ar+576+288+640+288+0+10%0Ad+688+288+640+288+1+0.805904783%0Aw+576+176+576+288+0%0Ag+752+304+752+368+0%0AR+576+176+544+176+1+2+200000+12+12+0+0.5%0Ac+896+160+896+240+0+1e-7+10.148817573020233%0Ag+896+240+896+256+0%0Ax+576+417+865+420+4+24+1%5Csnf%5Cs%5Cq%5Csgate%5Cscapacitance%0Ax+1022+425+1311+428+4+24+1%5Csnf%5Cs%5Cq%5Csgate%5Cscapacitance%0Ag+1344+240+1344+256+0%0Ac+1344+160+1344+240+0+1e-7+10.228288268136424%0AR+1024+144+992+144+1+2+200000+12+12+0+0.5%0Ag+1200+304+1200+368+0%0Aw+1024+144+1024+288+0%0Ar+1024+288+1136+288+0+470%0Ac+1136+320+1136+352+0+1e-9+22.708762233557245%0Aw+1136+288+1136+320+0%0Ag+1136+352+1136+368+0%0Ag+1136+208+1136+224+0%0Aw+1344+160+1392+160+2%0Ar+1280+160+1344+160+0+1000%0Aw+1200+160+1280+160+2%0Aw+1200+160+1200+272+0%0Af+1136+288+1200+288+0+1.5+0.2%0AR+1200+128+1200+80+0+0+40+24+0+0+0.5%0Aw+1136+144+1136+176+0%0Ac+1136+176+1136+208+0+1e-9+22.708743810397266%0Ar+1024+144+1136+144+0+470%0Af+1136+144+1200+144+1+1.5+0.2%0Ax+574+97+659+100+4+24+Do%5Csthis%0Ax+1001+108+1155+111+4+24+Don't%5Csdo%5Csthis%0Ao+7+64+0+4097+5+0.2+0+2+7+3%0Ao+4+64+0+4098+40+0.8+1+2+4+3%0Ao+17+64+0+4098+40+0.8+1+2+17+3%0Ao+43+64+0+4097+5+25.6+2+2+43+3%0Ao+45+64+0+4098+40+0.05+3+2+45+3%0Ao+34+64+0+4098+40+0.8+3+2+34+3%0A) one kind of half-bridge that adds some delay to the gate so when the gate goes from high to low, or low to high, then the correct MOS will turn off before activating the other one. Without the diodes in the link, you will activate both when the gate is at half of VDD => enormous current flowing => magic smoke.